# How to get the missing record Row number and column names using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Using python and pandas, I would like to achieve the output below. Whenever there are `Null` or `Nan` values present in the file then it needs to print the both row number and column name.

```
import pandas as pd

# List of Tuples
employees = [('Stuti', 'Null', 'Varanasi', 20000),
        ('Saumya', 'NAN', 'NAN', 35000),
        ('Saumya', 32, 'Delhi', 30000),
        ('Aaditya', 40, 'Dehradun', 24000),
        ('NAN', 45, 'Delhi', 70000)
        ]

# Create a DataFrame object from list
df = pd.DataFrame(employees,
            columns =['Name', 'Age',
            'City', 'Salary'])
print(df)
```

Expected Output:

```
Row 0: column Age missing
Row 1: Column Age, column City missing
Row 4: Column Name missing
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `isin` to mask the missing values, then matrix multiply `@` with the columns to concatenate them:

```
s = df.isin(['Null','NAN'])

missing = s.loc[s.any(1)] @ ('column ' + df.columns + ', ')
for r, val in missing.str[:-2].items():
    print(f'Row {r}: {val} is missing')
```

Output:

```
Row 0: column Age is missing
Row 1: column Age, column City is missing
Row 4: column Name is missing
```

Comment: it is not printing anything after reading csv file data from local. Do you have any suggestion on this?
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('names.csv')
print(df)

Comment: If you read the data from csv, `Null` and `NAN` may be replaced with `np.nan`. Try `s = df.isna()  | df.isin(['Null', 'NAN'])`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Working as expecting..